# Comparing String To Array Element?

Tags: arrays, string, compare, element

I have the following code:

```
public class Equals {

        String[] s1 = {"red", "white", "black", "blue"};
        String[] s2 = {"red", "black", "green"};
        String[] s3 = {"red", "green"};
```

What I need is to give me the following output:

Comparing String s1, s2, s3

red 3 matches. 
black 2 matches. 
green 2 matches.

Someone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Greetings!

Comment: What language are you using

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to display any element the occurs in more than two arrays?

Comment: http://java67.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-compare-two-arrays-in-java-string-int-example.html
Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very well written but is a quick solution to what you asked for. Basically, I added all of the arrays to a List and then iterated through that list checking if the selected element matched any of the given colours.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            String[] s1 = {"red", "white", "black", "blue"};
            String[] s2 = {"red", "black", "green"};
            String[] s3 = {"red", "green"};
            int red = 0;
            int black =0;
            int green = 0;
            int white= 0;
            int blue= 0;

            List <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1));
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s3));

           for(String s: list)
           {
               if(s.equals("red"))
                {
                   red++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("white"))
                {
                   white++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("black"))
                {
                   black++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("green"))
                {
                   green++;
                }
               else  if(s.equals("blue"))
                {
                   blue++;
                }

           }
            System.out.println(red + "  Red found\n" + green + "  Green Found\n" + white + "  White Found\n" + black + "  Black Found\n" + blue + "  Blue Found");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3  Red found
2  Green Found
1  White Found
2  Black Found
1  Blue Found
```